# Combinatorics on Committees

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A democratic group consists of 5 NY representatives, 3 NJ reps, 3 CA reps and 4 WA reps.

a. How many different committees of 8 members can be formed if there must be at least one rep from each state on the committee (assuming all reps from their respective states are on the same level and count the same).

I got that to mean that I could choose from NY NY NY NY NY NJ NJ NJ CA CA CA WA WA WA WA and I believe I have this one in c(5,1)*c(3,1)*c(3,1)*c(4,1)*c(11,4) = 59,400

b. Same situation however the reps from NY state require you consider their rank and therefore are now considered like NY1 NY2 NY3 NY4 NY5 NJ NJ NJ CA CA CA WA WA WA WA

because there are distinct differences does this become p(5,1)*c(3,1)*c(3,1)*c(4,1)*c(11,4) or is there more I need to consider? Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is quite this many; for instance, if you put no restrictions on the home states then you have $\binom{15}{8} = 6,435$ choices.

Comment: How does that guarantee that one from each state is represented though? in c(15,8) you could choose all NY and NJ and get 8 but that doesn't satisfy the at least one rep from each state part.

Comment: It doesn't, but it means that you have to have less than $6,435$ choices, because a few of the above choices won't count. I have a complete answer coming, but the above combination is a good starting point if you want to think about this problem a bit more!

Comment: Ah... gotcha. Should I lump the four I need together like NY NJ CA WA - 1 way and then find the other 4 using c(11,4)? That'll give me 330.

Comment: As you pointed out, there are committees that perhaps won't have the representatives you put together though.

Comment: If all the representatives are basically the same... all NY reps are the same, NJ reps etc... does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

A) There are $\binom{15}{8}$ total ways to form committees of 8 representatives. Of these, there are $\binom{12}{8}$ to form committees that lack a NJ representative, also $\binom{12}{8}$ ways to form committees that lack a CA representative, $\binom{10}{8}$ ways to form committees that lack a NY representative, and $\binom{11}{8}$ ways to form committees that lack a WA representative.

To avoid double counting, there are $\binom{9}{8} = 9$ ways to form a committee lacking both a NJ and CA representative. For committees that lack both an NY and NJ or NY and CA representative, there is $\binom{8}{8} = 1$ way. From the principle of inclusion and exclusion, these should be added back to the total (to account for the fact we removed these committees twice). Note there are no ways to form committees lacking another combination of states, nor are there any ways to form committees with representatives from only one state.

So in total, there are:

$$\binom{15}{8} - \binom{12}{8} - \binom{12}{8} - \binom{11}{8} - \binom{10}{8} + 9 + 2 = 5,246 $$

different committees.

B) One way to simplify this problem (and also do Part A) is to consider each case of possible number of NY representatives. The cases are 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1. You then solve the problem for Part A where you split the remaining members of the committee among the remaining representatives (still ensuring there is one per state).

I left my answer for Part A up, because we use a similar approach for each case and because you can verify both methods give the same answer.

Without ranks, for $n$ representatives from New York where $n\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ we have:

$$ \binom{5}{n} \left[ \binom{10}{8-n} - \binom{7}{8-n} - \binom{7}{8-n} - \binom{6}{8-n} \right] $$

different choices (note that last term is zero for $n=1$). Adding up the choices will give you the answer for Part A.

Now to find the solution to Part B, we multiply each case with the number of ways to rank the NY representatives, which is $n!$ and sum up. This gives:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{5} n! \binom{5}{n} \left[ \binom{10}{8-n} - \binom{7}{8-n} - \binom{7}{8-n} - \binom{6}{8-n} \right] = 36,170 $$